# Load Service on first page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I have a simple AngularJS service which handles date format conversion:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
    .service('DateUtils', function () {

        /**
         * Convert US -> EU date format OR EU -> US data format
         * @param date Date format yyyy-MM-dd OR dd-MM-yyyy
         * @returns {*} opposite of input
         */
        this.simpleDateFormatConverter = function (date) {
            if (date) {
                var benchmark = date.substr(0, 4);

                //  Check wether the first four digits are integers (US)
                var matches = benchmark.match("^[0-9]*$");

                //  if the date is US simple date format (yyyy-MM-dd)
                if (matches != null) {
                    var year = date.substr(0, 4);
                    var month = date.substr(5, 2);
                    var day = date.substr(8, 2);
                    // US -> EU
                    return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                } else {
                    var year = date.substr(6, 4);
                    var month = date.substr(3, 2);
                    var day = date.substr(0, 2);
                    // EU -> US
                    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        }
    });
```

Case: I have got an editing page, which is being filled with existing data of that entity. (In this case the birthdate **in US format**). In my controller, as seen below, I am injecting the service and using its function to convert the birthDate of the entity Author.

When visiting the editing page, the birthdate is in US format, but when refreshing the page, it gets converted as wished.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('AuthorEditController',
        ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'entity', 'Author', '$state', 'DateUtils',
            function ($scope, $stateParams, entity, Author, $state, DateUtils) {

                $scope.error = null;
                $scope.author = entity;

                $scope.load = function (id) {
                    Author.get({id: id}, function (result) {
                        $scope.author = result;
                    });
                };

                // Only working on page reload
                $scope.author.birthDate = DateUtils.simpleDateFormatConverter($scope.author.birthDate);

                $scope.save = function () {
                    // save author
                };

            }]);
```

Is it because my data has not been loaded correctly yet, therefore the data, which is undefined on that moment, cannot be manipulated by the service?

How can I make sure this is being done dynamically as for the first page load?

Answer (score 2):

It's because Author.get() returns a `promise`, therefore it's resolved in a separated thread. For your code to work, you should call the Date converter inside the callback function, like so:

```
$scope.load = function (id) {
                    Author.get({id: id}, function (result) {
                        $scope.author = result;
                        $scope.author.birthDate = DateUtils.simpleDateFormatConverter($scope.author.birthDate);

                    });
                };
```

If you are unfamiliar with promises you may want to do some study before continuing.

Take a look at:
http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: Careful with the thread comment. JavaScript is single threaded. The callback will be called on the same thread, but at another time.

Comment: Yes, in a technical analysis, JS treads are a fake parallelism. But programmatically it will be the same as a thread, so it doesn't seem necessary to point it out. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: If it was a thread, you would not be able to have a shared context, that is not able to access $scope. But I agree, this is not relevant for the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on. You are loading the author object in an asynchronous way, that means that the callback function containing the assignment `$scope.author = result;` will fire later on in most cases than your conversion happens. So as @Italo Ayres answered, you should execute your conversion in the callback function.

The behaviour that the data is converted correctly after refreshing the page could be another issue:

It seems that the `Author` service caches the result and returns the previously returned object. So please be aware that you just modified the object that is still under control of the `Author` service. This could lead to really hard to track errors when you are using the service in some other places. Consider placing your conversion into the service (if this is intended) or make a deep clone of the project given to you to not influence others. If it is just an UI issue, you could also add a function that only converts the data for displaying it without modifying the object at all. Think of what happens with the object when you save - do you really want to save the formatted date value?

Comment: The birthdate is entered as EU date format (dd-MM-yyyy) which is converted to US date format (yyyy-MM-dd) with AngularJS. This, because of the date datatype in the mySQL database. When displaying this on the UI, US date format code (from te server) is converted to EU date format by AngularJS again.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **[filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** for date is recommended than using a factory

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('DateUtils', function (date) {


if (date) {
                var benchmark = date.substr(0, 4);

                //  Check wether the first four digits are integers (US)
                var matches = benchmark.match("^[0-9]*$");

                //  if the date is US simple date format (yyyy-MM-dd)
                if (matches != null) {
                    var year = date.substr(0, 4);
                    var month = date.substr(5, 2);
                    var day = date.substr(8, 2);
                    // US -> EU
                  var result= day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                } else {
                    var year = date.substr(6, 4);
                    var month = date.substr(3, 2);
                    var day = date.substr(0, 2);
                    // EU -> US
                   var result= year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                }
            } else {
                var result= null;
            }



        return function (result) {

                return result;

        }


    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>{{yourDate | DateUtils }}</p>
```

There are also native Angular date **[formats](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)**

Comment: @Buggyy using filters will avoid you asking this question : "Is it because my data has not been loaded correctly" :) , that is all.